# UIBootstrap Tooltip Multiple Triggers

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is it possible to extend the triggers for Tooltip from UIBootstrap to accept multiple conditions.

For example I want my tooltip to close on 'blur' and 'click'.

I have tried to pass in an array but this does not work

```
$tooltipProvider.setTriggers({"click": ["blur", "click"]});
```

Answer (score 2):

The tooltip sets up the trigger by using the element.bind method with the hide and show triggers represented as 'showTrigger': 'hideTrigger'.  You should be able to use {"click": "blur click"} and have 'blur click" passed to the element.bind method as the first parameter.